# SQL Server: User-Define Function w/Table Parameters Filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table-valued function that filters `Table1` based upon values in `Table2` but apply NO filtering if `Table2` contains nothing.

I'm not good at SQL, so this is what I have thus far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@table2 Table2 READONLY)
    RETURNS TABLE
        AS RETURN (
        SELECT userID, first_name, last_name
        FROM Table1
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT user_ID FROM Table2 WHERE user_ID = Table1.user_ID AND user_security_group = 5)
)
```

In the above case, the function should return all users and their first/last names if they are in the `user_security_group` 5.

But if NO users exist within the `user_security_group` 5, I want to return ALL users (i.e. apply no filtering).  So, pseudo code like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@table2 Table2 READONLY)
    RETURNS TABLE
        AS RETURN (
        SELECT userID, first_name, last_name
        FROM Table1

        -- pseudo code here
        IF WHERE EXISTS (SELECT user_ID FROM Table2 WHERE user_ID = Table1.user_ID AND user_security_group = 5)
        -- THEN APPLY FILTERING
        -- ELSE DO NOT APPLY FILTERING

)
```

How do I achieve the desire functionality within `MyFunction`?  Thank you.

P.S. - the above example is the simple case.  Ideally, I'll be passing multiple tables as parameters into `MyFunction` and apply the same IF/ELSE logic to each parameter table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with a second condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    SELECT t1.userID, t1.first_name, t1.last_name
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.user_ID = t1.user_ID AND t2.user_security_group = 5) OR
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.user_security_group = 5) ;
```

Comment: But that would return both cases, no? Think he should go with count first and then have IF statement

Comment: @Veljko89 . . . Why not just let the SQL optimizer do the work?

Comment: @Veljko89 - what would your proposed COUNT + IF statement solution look like?  Thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I read your solution too quickly.  Your OR statement does work, very cool approach; thank you.